# Create different image state for toggle button in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a toggle button in my windows phone app that will act as a pause button and I want to have it so when the user clicks on it, it will pause and when they click on it again it will unpause. Unlike the image toggle button in the WinRT toolkit, I can't just choose the checked and unchecked states.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Global varialbe:

```
bool imageToggleTap = false;
```

and after in the Tap event from this toggle you can do something like:

```
if( imageToggleTap == false)
{
    // logic when toogle ON
    imageToggleTap = true;
}
else
{
    // logic when toogle OFF
    imageToggleTap = false;
}
```

I think you are asking for that, hope help it.